# Why do I have bad font anti-aliasing (colored halos) in Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, fonts

I just installed a fresh Kubuntu 18.04 and have a really bad font rendering, or better to say subpixel rendering.

The characters are surrounded by red and green halos. It's different, depending on which font I use, but it's visible everywhere.

It's especially bad in the kde menu and in the "synaptics terminal window".

[image: Synaptic terminal window]

It's not that bad in Konsole window, but still hard to read (especially the "m"s).

[image: Konsole window]

I tried every combination in the "Use anti-aliasing" settings but to no avail, except when I switch it all off.

I even tried to put this in to `/etc/environment`

```
FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35 cff:no-stem-darkening=1 autofitter:warping=1"
```

This is somewhat different but the surrounding colors are still there.

I am using Intel graphics from an i3 6100 CPU.

What can I do?

Comment: I too don't see any halos in either image. The difference between terminals maybe due to one being `root` and the other standard user.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see it on my screen, so it's probably something to do with [the subpixel arrangement in your monitor](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/subpixel.php) and Kubuntu thinking you have a different one than you have.

For KDE, the linked page recommends:

> [Go to] Control center > Display > Theme > Fonts > Configure anti-aliasing. Select the hinting level (slight or medium recommended) and the subpixel order (RGB, BGR, etc.).

Record the original settings somewhere and then you can try all the combinations to see if one helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (except it was a white halo around all of my font). I had the issue right before I installed my Nvidia GPU, and again when I uninstalled it.

Turns out, as [per this answer](https://superuser.com/a/340961/1768279) the issue had to do w/ my display (a TCL TV). I had a custom name for the PC's HDMI input. When I reverted it to the default label of 'Computer' the display was so crisp it took my breath away